# How to create tool like inspect or SPY for windows app?

Tags: inspect

can you please suggest to create tool similar like Inspect tool, i need to take the automation id dynamically for the element to use it for windows application

Comment: Software already exist , in old version of visual studio 6.0 ( before NET framework )  there is a extra tools . Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx

Comment: yes i need to incorporate this inspect tool functionality in my application..For that i need code vise advice to use this functinality